# censor bleep delay - sam broadcaster

Tags: microphone, voice, broadcast

So am needing software solution that will allow a radio presenter to replace incoming mic audio with a bleep sound or cut out the section of audio where a person swears on air.

We currently use the following software

- voicemeeter banana
- Sam Broadcaster pro

And an external mixer that the mics plug-in to which then connects to the pc.

Now in both voicemeeter and Sam Broadcaster we can set delay on mic input.

However in both cases we can't replace the audio with a sound.

In Sam Broadcaster we can turn mic on and turn mic off. Cutting out the section that the swearing happen.

With voicemeeter I would think that muting the channel that the audio is in with a delay would mean that we would again just have dead air and not a bleep sound.

So I am asking the question on here does anyone know how FM radio stations and TV station add that delay + bleep sound .

Answer (score 1):

An internet search will tell you what radio stations use. Keyword: “**profanity delay**”

If you are only able to use your current set up I would suggest having a channel with no delay on it that plays the bleep sound effect you want and is the trigger for a ducker assigned to the incoming microphone channel that needs censoring, which can be done in VM banana; I believe.